# how to undo system user creation

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, package-management

to troubleshoot a Ubuntu package manager problem I have to 
do

```
sudo deluser --system messagebus
```

I want to know what is the command to undo the above before I try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before any action, copy "/etc/passwd" to a safe place.

Then, to recreate the user:

```
adduser --system --home $HOME --shell $SHELL --uid $UID messagebus
```

HOME,SHELL,UID look in the copy you made of `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: Thanks I just wanted to be sure before doing hence asked here.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo adduser --system messagebus
```

check

```
man adduser
```